# Preventing form from being resubmitted too quickly in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

On reddit they only allow newer users to make new posts every ten minutes. I want to do something similar. This is what I have been doing up to this point.

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['content']))
    $firsttime = time();

if (!empty($_REQUEST['content']))
    $secondtime = time();

if ($secondtime - $firsttime < 10*60*60)
    echo 'You are resubmitting too quickly.';
```

It works just for first time. Even then, there is a problem, I don't want it to work first time but only when user submits second time and so on. Is there something in PHP or in JavaScript to do this. I would prefer a PHP version.
**I am not talking about form resubmission on page refresh here.**

On basis of suggestion in comments I arrived at following result

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['firsttime'])&&(form submission successful))
 $_SESSION['firsttime'] = time();
 else if(isset($_SESSION['firsttime']&&(time()-$_SESSION['firsttime'] > 60*10*10)
 submit form
 else if(isset($_SESSION['firsttime']&&(time()-$_SESSION['firsttime'] < 60*10*10)
 please wait for sometime.
```

Is this pseudocode correct?

Comment: Are we talking about the first time on the page in the browser or the first time a new user has ever posted something? Such that the "First Time" will only be once per user. The first case you can use a session to keep track, the second case you need to use your DB.

Comment: You would need to set some information in a session or cookie variable that tested the time.

Comment: The first time on the page in the browser.

Comment: Is there any tutorial somewhere related to this? or any other helpful link.

Comment: Don't rely on anything in `$_REQUEST`.  When first post happens, you can just add 10 minutes to the time of that POST and save a session variable with that time to compare against to see if user can make another POST.

Comment: But if you used a cookie or session based checking, if I clear my cookies, I can post in every sec, because the PHP will see me as a first-timer. The better way would be to check the last comment's datetime in the database and compare to this, not some session time.

Comment: @Fenistil You **can't** clear a session in PHP from the clients side.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: If I clear all my cookies, the server can't identify me, so it needs to assign me a new session. Yes I can't clear the old one, but can have a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what time they last posted at instead of using time() twice.
If you are saving your posts to a database, then you're probably saving a time stamp with them.

So a simple way to do this is select any posts matching this user with a time stamp less then 10 minutes ago. If the query returns anything, don't let them post. Your query could be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE (poster = **userid**) AND (post_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

If the query returns 0, save the post - along with it's time stamp.

Of course, that's just a rough idea of how it would look, it's going to depend on how you're storing your posts. Point is, since by definition the user is saving a post here you already have a record of what they last saved - so all you need to do is check it against the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the access time into the session and then when the script gets called check if the current access time was more 10 minutes ago.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['last_time'])) 
{
  if($_SESSION['last_time']+10*60*60<now()) echo "too fast";
}
$_SESSION['last_time'] =  now();
```